# sacar al Promedio Consulta ELOQUENT ORM LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm

¿Cómo podría sacar el promedio de una consulta?

tengo una Tabla llamada

```
Publicaciones
```

Otra tabla llamada `Puntuaciones`

Otra `Usuarios`

Otra `Fotos`

```
Usuarios > Publicaciones > Comentarios  | Fotos
```

*Entonces cuando hago mi consulta de publicaciones, Cargo los usuarios a los que le pertenece esa publicación de está forma.*

```html
  $publicaciones =  Publicacion::with(['usuario','fotos','comentarios'])
       ->whereHas('fotos')
       ->where('categoria_id',$categoria->id)
       ->paginate(10);
```

Pero resulta que en la tabla comentarios tengo un campo llamado Puntuación

Lo intente de esta forma pero no hace nada.

```html
  $publicaciones =  Publicacion::with(['usuario','fotos','comentarios' => function($q) {
           return $q->avg('puntuacion');
       }])
       ->whereHas('fotos')
       ->where('categoria_id',$categoria->id)
       ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Comentarios con quien esta vinculada?

Comment: Publicaciones - Comentarios